# How can I provide a custom query for deleteAll in Spring data Couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-data, repository, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I need a custom query (due to entity subclassing) for my deleteAll repository method such as (Kotlin code):

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.delete} WHERE (_class='a.b.C' OR _class='d.e.F')")
override fun deleteAll()
```

However, when running this I get:

```
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Query returning a primitive type are expected to return exactly 1 result, got 0
```

I cannot find an example how to provide a custom query for a deleteAll method, which (by interface signature) cannot return anything.

Comment: Ok, I can provide a method such as `fun deleteTheLot(): List<X>` -- still I am interested on how to override the 'deleteAll()` method with a custom query